# Sublime Text 3 - Middle click paste in Windows OS

Tags: sublimetext3

In Linux (Ubuntu and Lubuntu) this feature for selecting some text with mouse and pasting it with middle click in Sublime Text works perfectly, but in windows OS it doesn't work.

Is there some package to install it or else?

How to make middle click paste work in Sublime Text 3 on Windows OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sublime goto:

```
Preferences->Browse Packages
```

It should bring up your windows explorer. In that explorer click the User folder In that folder make a file called:

```
Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap
```

Finally in that file put:

```
[ { "button": "button3", "modifiers": [], "command": "paste" } ]
```

Save and restart sublime.

Comment: I would like it to when i middle click my mouse that it pastes what is in clipboard....how to do that? And also when i select text that it copies it in clipboard

Comment: Okay in sublime goto:
Preferences->Browse Packages

It should bring up your windows explorer.

In that explorer click the User folder

In that folder make a file called: Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap

and finally in that file put: 
[
 { "button": "button3", "modifiers": [], "command": "paste" }
]

Save and restart sublime :)

Comment: copy change the command to copy. and for selection it depends what you want: you have a couple choices. "command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "scope"} }, OR "command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "brackets"} }, OR "command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "indentation"} }, OR ["ctrl+shift+a"], "command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "tag"} },

Comment: I just want to select with left mouse click and that it copies it all to clipboard like in Putty. How to make that one?

Comment: Oh so like, you highlight with left click and as soon as you release it copies whatever was highlighted?

Comment: Yesss...that one! I found this, but it doesn't work:  { "button": "button1", "modifiers": ["alt"], "command": "goto_python_definition", "press_command": "drag_select" }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121912/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-tim-hinz).

Comment: @TimHinz please [edit] your answer to add new information, do not put it in comments, which may be removed at any time. Remember, answers are not primarily for the person who posted the question, but for the many users that will see this question later. As it stands now, your answer is both incomplete and incorrect, as it doesn't address the OP's actual question of reprogramming the mouse's functionality.